# Can you apply water based stain over oil based wood conditioner?

Tags: staining

I put oil based wood conditioner on and but would rather used water based conditioner and stain.  I am able to put on water based stain over the oil based conditioner?  Or is there a way to remove the oil based conditioner?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you list what you used please? Exact product names, not just the brand.

Comment: You could apply a coat of a shellac based product between the oil based product and the water based product.

Answer (score 1):

I would give it a try on a spare piece of wood. But removal/cleanup should be listed on the product can. Most likely will be mineral spirits. I don't use water-based products on wood, so I guess I'd have to ask what the benefits are. Penetrating stain cleans up with mineral spirits and is easy to apply, just make sure you wipe the extra off before it gets sticky. Danish oil is even easier if you aren't following up with poly.

Comment: Water based stains have more colors available off the shelf, in my experience. That could be one benefit.